# Are the reputation notifications broken again?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, notification-bar

It seems notifications on new reputation gained is broken again.

> [image: screenshot]

Notifications on comments are not affected. It seems to happen quite often nowadays. Is there a problem with it? Can it be fixed please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update:** fix is live, queue is draining from 170k entries now. All should be well in under 5 minutes.

---

There was a new change to this system this morning that added a new reputation type for suggested edit overrides...but the aggregator, upon seeing the first one, promptly threw a fit (it hadn't been build to see this new enum type yet).

A fix is building out now which will drain the redis queue as soon as it accepts the new type as valid and moves along. A current top-level view of the aggregator queue (we rack up items quickly):
[image]

Comment: There they are!

Comment: *"All should be well in under 5 minutes"* - I also am experiencing that problem; that 5 minutes sure is taking a while *lol*. Does this have to propagate over to each member in different areas, or should it have taken effect on a global area? This has been happening for almost an hour for me now. Not big issue, just thought I'd mention that and I posted a question about it on the other meta https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348239/1415724

Comment: @Fred-ii-the queue is already flushed - what are you seeing or not seeing?

Comment: I'm actually still seeing the same thing from my screencap that I provided in my meta question; I edited my comment above to contain the link to it. I was expecting to see more +1's and +5 for one I received.