# SO network was very slow

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

A few hours ago all SO network sites were loading very slow. Chrome was showing page by loaded parts. It was because of slow downloading an html page (other files were loaded quickly). Here is a [screenvideo](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4Wq4/ECYyKg9BS) of the problem.

According to twitter it was related to migration to .NET Core:

[image: twitter screenshot]

It would be interesting to find out more technical detais about the reasons of the problem.

Comment: I've been facing this for the last 2 days.

Comment: Some details: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316336/reputation-notifications-seem-to-be-broken-again/316349#316349

Comment: @Shog9, that post was written at 2018-10-05 06:03:17Z, but a problem (at least on ruSO) was fixed near 2018-10-05 17:37:14Z and appeared not earlier than 2018-10-05 08:39:30Z. So the time doesn't match and it may be the other problem. Also that question has very few technical details.

Comment: @Suvitruf, it wasn't 2 days. There was no such problem today in the morning. Or, at least it have not had such scale (maybe different load by part of the day?).

Comment: What do you mean by *"Chrome was showing page by loaded parts"*? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, I think, you can see it on video? Firstly the header is shown. Some time after that top banner appears. Then left menu. A few questions. Some more questions multiple times. The footer. Right sidebar. And finally the banner at the right sidebar. Then page load finishes.

Comment: Since this was a transient event and fixed up during - marking this as status-completed.