# Not notified of all rep changes, old bug returns

Tags: bug, reputation, notifications

This seems to be a reincarnation of [Reputation notifications seem to be broken again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316336/323179), which was marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). So: [status-uncompleted](/questions/tagged/status-uncompleted).

Today (Feb 6th) on Science Fiction and Fantasy I reached the rep cap (+200 points exactly), as shown by [my profile](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/82909/laurel?tab=reputation) (there are no deleted post notifications for today).

However, I appeared to rep cap at 180 in the drop down:

> [image]

Can this be fixed?

---

(Note that since I posted this question, one of my answers was accepted so the totals are +15 points higher—but I'm still missing 20 points.)